# Definability and Models of a first-order theory of cardinals

Tags: logic, set-theory, first-order-logic, cardinals

Let $\mathcal{M}=(\mathrm{Card},<,x \mapsto \aleph_x)$. Also, have $C_0 = \{\kappa \ |\ \aleph_\kappa = \kappa\}$, and $C_{n+1} = \{\kappa \ |\ \kappa = \sup (C_n \cap \kappa)\}$.
One can see quite easily that arbitrarily large elements of any $C_n$ are definable in $\mathcal{M}$. Thus, a question arises: Is the least cardinal $\kappa$ that is closed under the operations imposed by each $C_n$ elementarily equivalent to $\mathcal{M}$, and is the existence of such a cardinal provable in ZFC?

Comment: "arbitrarily large elements of any $C_n$ are definable in $\mathcal{M}$" I don't understand this claim. Only countably many things in $\mathcal{M}$ are definable at all, and any countable subset of $\mathcal{M}$ is bounded. And if you mean "definable with parameters," then *every* element of $\mathcal{M}$ is definable with parameters in $\mathcal{M}$.

Comment: Also, what are "the operations imposed" by a given $C_n$?

Comment: @NoahSchweber You're right of course, I'll edit the question to reflect what I mean when I have enough time to rethink it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a partial answer, this cardinal exists. It is the $\omega^\omega$th fixed point. To see why, note that $C_0$ is just the class of fixed points, and $C_1$ is the limits of fixed points (which are themselves fixed points, easily). So the least member of $C_1$ is the $\omega$th fixed point. Similarly, $C_2$ is the limit of limits of fixed points, so the least such cardinal is the $\omega^2$ fixed point, etc.

So the cardinal you're looking for is indeed the $\omega^\omega$th fixed point.

Comment: If my memory serves me right $\omega^\omega\prec\rm Ord$, and that suggests that the answer to the rest of the question is positive.